# DSolve giving error output solving a nonlinear PDE

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I try to solve the following PDE:
`sol = DSolveValue[D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]/D[u[x, t], {x, 1}], u[x, t], {x, t}]`
the output is:
`C[1][t] + C[2][t + x]`
Obviously it is a wrong solution, I want to know what happen with MMA.

Comment: please report to WRI. It looks like wrong template is used for the pde.

Comment: This `DSolveValue[D[u[x,t],x,t]==D[u[x,t],{x,2}],u[x,t],{x,t}]` gives exactly the same answer, but it is a different PDE...

Comment: @Nasser How I can get the Method of NDSolve  the default option is Automatic. My thought is that if I can change some option to solve the PDE

Comment: @user293787 An interesting coincidence.

Comment: @user293787 In your case the solution is correct, however.